# Plot REST API response using Plotly and AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to assign a and b values from the json {month,consumption}?

REST API response:

```
data= {
    "_id": {
    "$oid": "580b8f80c2ef1645d285c884"
    },
    "year": "2012",
    "state": "Indiana",
    "consumption": 3275,
    "month": "january"
    },
    {
    "_id": {
    "$oid": "580b8f81bd966f4110af0111"
    },
    "year": "2012",
    "state": "Indiana",
    "consumption": 6348,
    "month": "february"
    }
```

app.js:

```
var graphPlotterDemoApp = angular.module('graphPlotterDemoApp', ['graphPlotter']);

graphPlotterDemoApp.controller('graphPlotterDemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    var a = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr"];
    var b = [10, 15, 13, 17];


    $scope.data={};
    $scope.refresh =  function(){
      $http.get("https://api.mlab.com/api/1/databases/energyx/collections/energydata_2012?&apiKey=6JzRAzvdeqyLKAfQAqMOsLYLvvIdJG6A")
        .success(function(response) {
           $scope.data = response.data;
        });

    };


    var trace1 = {
        x: a,
        y: b,
        type: 'scatter'
    };


    $scope.refresh();

    $scope.graphPlots = [trace1];
});
```

Comment: $scope.data._id[0].consumption you get  '0' th postion like that you want whole data use foreach get all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use like to get data from json

```
 var a=$scope.data.map(function(a) {return a.month;})
 var b=$scope.data.map(function(a) {return a.consumption;})
```